Error: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1
I am encountering an error to my flutter project. I wanted to add firebase service to my flutter project. However when I am following the steps from Firebase by adding the google-json file to my android/app directory and also adding the codes dependencies to both project level and app level build.gradle file. The error of imcompatible version of Kotlin prompted up.
The errors message are
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details

BUILD FAILED in 50s

┌─ Flutter Fix ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                     │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then │
│ update C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\projectApp\android\build.gradle:  │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'                                                    │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

This is my android/build.gradle file
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.1'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
//        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}


plugins {
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.4.1' apply false
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}



rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


This is the android/app/build.gradle file
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.rtwo"
    compileSdk flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.rtwo"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.8.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}



//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


Since you asked the question a month ago I guess you are using latest flutter version. I created a new flutter project, I needed to use geolocator, shared_preference package, after writing the necessary code to ask for user permission to get their location, i tried running the project using
flutter run

I got the same error you got, what i did was to just change
from
id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.10" apply false

to
id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.0" apply false

no need for the code below that you added
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.1'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
//        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

In summary, you only need to make changes in settings.gradle file.
I am not so sure if the new installation of android studio I did helped in fixing the problem. so try without new android studio installation, if the problem persist, do a new installation of android studio, it might solve the problem.
Please mark as accepted answer, if it solved the problem. Thank you

This answer is the correct one, I spent hours and hours, thank you very much!

Try to update Kotlin version in this line:
ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.1'

Metadata version seems to be 1.9.0. So you can replace that line with the latest Kotlin version number inside android/build.gradle:
ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.23'

Also make sure that you are not changing wrong line or anything else other than what Firebase documentation states.
Update:
After investigating carefully, seems like Kotlin version also defined inside Android/settings.gradle file like below:
id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.10" apply false

We need to update version number there to the latest Kotlin version which is 1.9.23 currently. So corrected line will be like this:
id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.23" apply false

If Kotlin number is updated here, no need to make any other changes inside build.gradle files. This version number here overrides whatever defined inside build.gradle files.

I have tried this it doesn't work. The same error prompts when i start running the app

Have you tried 'flutter clean' command first? Build gradle file changes require cleaning build folder usually. And double check why this line is commented: classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version" If that line is commented, updated Kotlin version will not do anything.

yes. I have tried  flutter clean command and also Invalidate the caches but nothing seems to work

How about the commented line? Why did you comment that?

Actually in the firebase documentation there is nothing of ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0' is mentioned to be added to the build.gradle file but I've been facing some errors so I search online for solution and saw that a lof of the build.gradle file have this line of code. Hence I manually added this and classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version" but then this error prompted up so i commented it to debug one by one
This error is indicating the settings.gradle file

After uncommenting the code I got a new error
`* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.3.0']

Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.application'.
class org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings_Decorated cannot be cast to class org.gradle.api.Project (org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings_Decorated and org.gradle.api.Project are in unnamed module of loader org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader @5c3bd550)`


Is it demo app? Can you provide source code so I can have a look

I found that issue when I attached geolocator: ^12.0.0 plugin to my project.
The solution was, as Raphael Tunji wrote (thank you), only one line modiffication in settings.gradle: org.jetbrains.kotlin.android
version bumped from 1.7.10 to 1.9.24
plugins {
  (...)
  id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.24" apply false
  (...)
}


If you get the error messages related to kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module look like this
e: /var/home/eymeric/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.9.0/8ee15ef0c67dc83d874f412d84378d7f0eb50b63/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /var/home/eymeric/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.9.0/8ee15ef0c67dc83d874f412d84378d7f0eb50b63/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /var/home/eymeric/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.9.0/8ee15ef0c67dc83d874f412d84378d7f0eb50b63/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /var/home/eymeric/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.9.0/cd65c21cfd1eec4d44ef09f9f52b6d9f8a720636/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.

This fix may be useful for you. In this case, I just leaved ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.20 but having changed the AGP version to 8.1.0 and the Gradle version to 8.0 (AGP 8.1.0 has required Gradle >= 8.0).
Almost pub packages in my project use Kotlin 1.7.20 so I set Kotlin to 1.7.20 to satisfy them to avoid other incompatible errors
One more thing you may need to update your settings.gradle, build.gradle(android) and build.gradle(app) follow this document to satisfy with AGP newer than 8.x.
This comment explained why need to use AGP newer than 8.x.
